# Consume WCF on ios device, convert from Windows Form application

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am currently converting a Windows Form application to ios. The windows implementation uses WCF net.tcp and System.Web.Security.Membership.

I have recompiled the shared entities and created a new basicHTTP endpoint with SSL.

What is the equivalent call to System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(user,pass) 
Is there one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, you need to handle the authentication separately, either with a separate service or create a web request to your service/Authentication_JSON_AppService.axd and get the token.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably have to create a new `[OperationContract]` on your WCF service to handle this.  Your server can definitely call these methods no problem.

I would guess these kind of things aren't available in MonoTouch, it seems very Windows specific.  (MonoTouch is a subset of .Net very similar to Silverlight)